# auto generated value PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to generate a value, not on database-side like auto key stuff, but on the front end or on the client side.. Do you have any clever idea to do that? Because Booking ref is not my primary key, it can't be autogenerated. What I want to do is to have an initial value of 10307 then increment it, whenever user/s create/s new record.

But what I've tried so far is this in PHP:

```
private function inputBookingRef() {
    $value = $this->bookingRef;
    $html = "";
    $value = 10307;
    $value++;
    $html .= '<label for="ref">Booking Ref: </label>';
    $html .= HTML::inputText("ref", 20, $value) . PHP_EOL;
    return $html;
}
```

**NOTE:**
My initial value is 10307, then I use the increment operator to make it 10308. But every time I create another record it just gives 10308. I think there must be some clever way to make it increment.

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean on the front end? as in the client side on their browser??

Comment: That's PHP code, how does that help explain the question? Show us what you're trying to do and explain it better.

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes there is a clever way, pass in the current (largest) value into the function.

Comment: your value will ALWAYS be 10308 since you are setting it to 10307 every time before the increment...

Comment: @sachleen Can you some me how to do that? thanks.

Comment: even if he adds an argument to the function and passes a number, he wont know what number to pass in there especialy if there are multiple sessions open

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes it would be better if you explained what problem you're trying to solve by this. There's probably a better way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: @sachleen Because Booking ref is not my primary key, it can't be autogenerated. What I want to do is to have an initial value of 10307 then increment it, whenever user/s create/s new record.

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes are you saving this id in the database

Comment: @Sibu yes I'm saving booking ref into the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are saving the value in db, you just have to fetch the value from database and pass that value to your function, so everytime it will be incrementing your previous value.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(ref_id) FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");//Getting the max ref_id
$values = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
inputBookingRef($values['ref_id'])//calling the function

private function inputBookingRef($value) {
    //$value = $this->bookingRef;
    $html = "";
    //$value = 10307;
    $value++;
    $html .= '<label for="ref">Booking Ref: </label>';
    $html .= HTML::inputText("ref", 20, $value) . PHP_EOL;
    return $html;
}
```

And fnally Insert the new $value into the Db

Comment: so   $query = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(ref_id) FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");//Getting the max ref_id
   $values = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
   inputBookingRef($values['ref_id']); will be placed in my back-end code?

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes No, see everytime user creates a new record get the max id inserted in db, increment it pass that value to the function and when user saves the value insert the incremented value

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes also as Eyal said along with number pass some function like uniqid so that no two user will same value.

Comment: I've got a warning message in here: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\RMS\pages\CreateBallpark.php then it starts with number 1? But I want it to start from the last record like 10307?

Comment: hello, i forgot to put the tble_name, it's fixed now but the problem is it's not getting the next number like 10307.

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes can you show the code ??, after fetching the values you have to increment it, and when the current row is inserted, this increment is saved. if you show the code, i can tell where you are going wrong

Comment: this is the im working on please check here: http://pastebin.com/CAN8TXXc thanks @Sibu

Answer (score 0):

If all you're looking for is a unique number, simply use PHP's `time` function and use the current seconds since epoch.

```
$unique_num = time();
```

Comment: Yes, much better to use uniqid() which uses microtime plus an optional server-specific prefix (see Eyal's answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you need a unique id using php with no database in the works use [uniquid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

but i still dont understand what you are trying to acomplish here